# Why am I getting a 404 error for aspx?

Tags: asp.net, iis, http-status-code-404

I inherited a website from another developer.  I was told it uses .NET 3.5. It runs fine in Visual Studio, but if I try to run it in IIS, I get a 404 error.  The strange part is, if I put an html or a "Hello World" aspx file in the website root, IIS is able to return the page perfectly fine.  I only get 404 errors on pages that were part of the original site.

Comment: 404 errors means that you are hitting a url that does not exist. Check the your IIS settings

Answer (score 0):

see and learn:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315122

Comment: 404 problem is now fixed. However, I only got it working on my local development system, which is running IIS 7.  There was some code in the website that was directing all traffic to a 404 error page if the domain wasn't in it's list of approved domains. I moved the website--which included an updated list of approved domains--to my production environment, but now I have another problem.  The index.aspx page displays fine, but any other page shows up as a 404. Even though, this is now working in development. I looked over your link and everything is set correctly. Any other ideas?

Comment: @Tuan I think this is issue of `relative and absolute` path.Without see your application its impossible to solve.